# Apache Spark Executors Dead - is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a pipeline to process my data on Spark. It seems like my Executors die every now and then when they reach near the Storage Memory limit. The job continues and eventually finishes but is this the normal behaviour? Is there something I should be doing to prevent this from happening? Every time this happens the job hangs for some time until (and I am guessing here) YARN provides some new executors for the job to continue.

[image: Spark UI Executor tab]

Answer (score 1):

I think this turned out to be related with a Yarn bug. It doesn't happen anymore after I set the following YARN options like suggested in section 4. of this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/)

> Best practice 5: Always set the virtual and physical memory check flag
>   to false.
>
> "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled":"false",
>
> "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled":"false"